# Reconciling to a non-parent version in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, versioning, reconcile

I am trying to find a neat way to clone a GDB version in ArcGIS and as suggested in [Cloning a transactional version in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130011/cloning-a-transactional-version-in-arcgis), it seems reconciling from the source to the clone is the way to go. However, my tests with both ArcMap and Arcpy suggest that the system will basically ignore reconciliation to a non-parent. Is there anyway to reconcile a version to some other or basically copy changes associated with it to another version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending couple of hours with ESRI support, I concluded that it is not possible through ArcGIS. However, if you are willing to fiddle with your underlying database, you can hack the versions table to temporarily change any version's parent to virtully any other temporatily and then reconcile and post as desired. Of course you do all that at your own risk.